# vbscript equvalent of fpassthru/readfile

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm looking for the vbscript/classic asp equivalent of fpassthru or readfile

I have some urls http://site/images/resized/100/100/image.gif

if this is not found, I have a image404.asp, which gets called instead, which 
reads the original image, resizes it and both sends it to the browser, and stores it at the proper location, so the 404 is no longer called.

This is transparent to the browser.

Now I wants to send different files depending on some conditions.

So i have two versions:

```
 c:/outsidewebroot/images/prudes/100/100/image.gif
 c:/outsidewebroot/images/x-rate/100/100/image.gif
```

The files are intentionally outside the webroot, so I cannot do a 302 redirect to it.

Instead of having to read the file into a vbscript variable and send it, is it possible to instruct the server to send the content of the file directly?

(To be able to use google adwords, we can not show female nipples or genitials, while male nipples and genitials are OK. WTF?!?)

Comment: I think a combination of `Server.Transfer` and the `ADODB.Stream` object to read the file and output it will work. You'll need `Response.BinaryWrite()` to output the binary returned by the stream object.

Comment: I'm already using Response.BinaryWrite(), I'm trying to avoid that. 
I will be looking into Server.Transfer, but can it read outside the webroot?